# How does the custom page Values[] array work in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

For example:

1. Panel
2. Label
3. Radio
4. Radio
5. Radio
6. Panel
7. Label
8. Radio
9. Radio
10. Label
11. Combo
12. Label
13. Label
14. Text
15. Button

Does the `Values` array match all of the controls on the page, or only the radio, combo, text controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic custom page has no `Values` property.

Only special implementations of a custom page do. And their meaning differs with the implementation.

- [`CreateInputQueryPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputquerypage)/[`TInputQueryWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputQueryWizardPage) – `Values` refers to text value of edit boxes added by `TInputQueryWizardPage.Add`.
- [`CreateInputOptionPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputoptionpage)/[`TInputOptionWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputOptionWizardPage) – `Values` refers to state of checkboxes/radiobuttons added by `TInputOptionWizardPage.Add`.
- [`CreateInputDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage)/[`TInputDirWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputDirWizardPage) – `Values` refers to text value of edit boxes added by `TInputDirWizardPage.Add`.
- [`CreateInputFilePage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputfilepage)/[`TInputFileWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputFileWizardPage) – `Values` refers to text value of edit boxes added by `TInputFileWizardPage.Add`.

---

If you want to refer to a value of a custom control added to a generic custom page, use the instance of the control. There's no (nice) way to refer to the control value via the container page.

- `TNewEdit.Text` – See [Inno Setup Edit installed file according to user preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39467048/850848)
- `TNewCheckBox.Checked` – See [Inno Setup: How to show (hide/unhide) password on checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55435520/850848)
- `TNewRadioButton.Checked` – See [Replacing Inno Setup installation type combo box with radio buttons on separate page (Install Shield like)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50446128/850848) or [How to create two LicenseFile pages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34592002/850848)
- `TNewCheckListBox.Checked` – See [How to split tasklist at tasks page of Inno Setup into multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886178/850848)
- etc.

That usually means that instances of controls you want to query later has to be global variables. See [Reading values from custom Inno Setup wizard pages without using global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792593/850848) or [Inno Setup: Access to custom control from OnClick event of another control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36839988/850848).